# Finding the difference in time in excel

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

Hopefully this is a better phrased question...  Ultimately what I'm trying to do is figure out if someone is late or not.  So I have their shift start times... it's in a string format of XXX-####, e.i. Sun-0320.   I also have a timestamp(Macro) of when they clocked in same format as Now()

So currently I have it as

```
A1 = Now()
B1 = Right(F1,4)
F1 = ShiftCode

C1 = A1-B1
```

A1 and B1 are both formatted to custom time of hh:mm
C1 is formatted as numbers. i tried time also

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1):

The NOW() function returns both the date and time, which changes as your cell/worksheet/workbook is being updated.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/now-function-3337fd29-145a-4347-b2e6-20c904739c46

There is a lot of options to add or subtract the time in excel, like here:

https://superuser.com/questions/89045/how-to-get-time-difference-as-minutes-in-excel

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/calculate-the-difference-between-two-times-e1c78778-749b-49a3-b13e-737715505ff6

https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2015/06/24/calculate-time-excel/

https://www.excel-easy.com/examples/time-difference.html

https://exceljet.net/formula/calculate-number-of-hours-between-two-times

but regarding your case I would rather use something like this:

instead of

```
  =NOW()
```

expand the formula, by adding another TEXT function and defining the time units for it:

```
 =TEXT(NOW(),"hh:mm:ss")
```

Then if you have another cell with a time value, you can easily add or subtract from the cell defined by the aforementioned formula.

[image]

Comment: Its a macro doing the now()... what I'm trying to check is if C1 is greater say 10 minutes

Comment: The NOW() is the Excel function, no macro needed.

Comment: While I can use now() as a timestamp function, having it as a recursive formula such as. ... IF(A1="",""",NOW())... and messing with the iterations settings.. the issue is whenever the document is refreshed.. it updates it.. especially if other macros are running also.  Which why the macro is used.

Comment: That's also going off topic.   I just want to be able to compare the two time and see if its greater than say 10 minutes or not.  So I really should do is  A1-B1>10... and I can't seem figure out that part